# SharePoint : Better Large Pages Library Approach

Tags: publishing-site, publishing-page, taxonomy, content-organizer

I'm working on project migration from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010.

The application build on SharePoint 2007 platform was years back and it contains a lots of data (approximately 100GB in total).

Basically it consists of large Pages Libraries ( > 3000 pages with approval workflow) within 4 Sub Sites (average about 700++ pages each).

I was looking for some solution manage to optimize the performance of large Pages Libraries after migration to SharePoint 2010, in term of Search and Navigation which allow easy access to the pages. Or even change of taxonomy design could improve the performance of publishing page.

According to TechNet article http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721053.aspx and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424402.aspx stated Content Organizer feature in SharePoint 2010 provide better management to pages.

However, I would like to seek for opinions from you guys for better solutions and approach.

Comment: any feedback???

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is that the # of pages is going to continue to grow on these sites, then using the Content Organizer and routing rules is the best approach for physically organizing pages into a folder hierarchy. You will need to figure out a file plan in which to organize pages (can be based on date) or it can be based on some sort of metadata fields, or by content type associated with the page layouts.

With this # of pages, clearly the standard navigation menus are not going to work, so you need to turn of the "Show Pages" on the out-of-box navigation, and come up with a strategy for how you want to implement dynamic navigation tools. Examples of integrating dynamic navigation into your site design include:

- Most Recent Pages based on a CQWP
- Most Popular Pages based on either page view analytics or ratings
- Pages by Topic/Category based on CQWP, grouping, and a metadata field

Is there a reason why you don't think the recommendations in the planning guides you linked to are not a good approach?